# Можно ли изменить формат EXCEL из *.xls в *.xlsx не прибегая к Interop?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Можно ли изменить формат EXCEL из *.xls в *.xlsx не прибегая к Interop и другим компонентам офиса?

После того, как сменю формат, я хочу работать через EppPlus(OpenXml).

Comment: Если из *.xls вам важны только данные, можно их вытащить с помощью OleDb-провайдера Jet

Answer (score 1):

Можно:
1) Используете библиотеки вроде NPOI, кстати, некоторые из них в отличие от OpenXml могут сразу работать с XLS, реализуют оба формата, но нет гарантий, что реализуют полностью.
2) Используете облако - готовые онлайн-сервисы (для них всех до единого возможно написать бот) или собственный сервер (VPS) со своим ПО.